# Automorphism group of $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z) \rtimes \Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, infinite-groups, automorphism-group

Automorphism group of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is $SL(3,\Bbb Z)$. I am wondering what the automorphism group of $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z) \rtimes \Bbb Z$ would be. Lets say the generators of the three $\Bbb Z$s in $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z) \rtimes \Bbb Z$ are $a,b,$ and $c$ respectively. $c$ acts on $a$ and $b$ as, $cac^{-1}=b^{-1}; cbc^{-1}=a$.

Comment: Thus you talk about $\Bbb Z^2\rtimes \Bbb Z$, which is probably not the same as $\Bbb Z\times (\Bbb Z\rtimes \Bbb Z)$